# Finding next open port

Tags: bash, unix, shell, cygwin

Is there any way, using basic Unix commands, to find the next unused port number, starting at port 4444 and going upwards?  I'm ssh'ed (via openssh) into a Windows XP machine, running Cygwin tools and using a bash shell.

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: Any method other than actually trying to open the port will be racy. Don't rely on that, just try to open/use it, move on to the next if it fails.

Comment: Are you trying to see if the windows box has an unused port, or the machine you are connected from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
for port in $(seq 4444 65000); do echo -ne "\035" | telnet 127.0.0.1 $port > /dev/null 2>&1; [ $? -eq 1 ] && echo "unused $port" && break; done
```

where

```
seq 4444 65000 - port range for check
echo -ne "\035" - escape character to force close telnet session (^])
```

if telnet finishes with exit code 1 that mean connection refused:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 4444
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
$ echo $?
1
```

else we decided that connection was success with exit code 0.

**EDIT:**
Special for cygwin: You need to install additional package `inetutils` that is contain telnet port and use the script as follows:

```
for port in $(seq 4444 65000); do echo -ne "\035" | /usr/bin/telnet 127.0.0.1 $port > /dev/null 2>&1; [ $? -eq 1 ] && echo "unused $port" && break; done
```

Comment: Although this solution works perfectly on a Linux platform, when I fire up Cygwin on Windows XP, it doesn't do anything.  In fact, running the command "telnet localhost 4444" does nothing (nothing is printed), even when there is a process running on 4444.

Comment: I suppose you need to check telnet. Just setup cygwin on my machine and it works (telnet) but the script doesn't. The problem in telnet exit code that is in windows terms %errorlevel% variable value. telnet doesn't return desired exit code that is expected in script.

Comment: Check the EDIT section of the answer. On my machine it works!

Comment: You are a man amongst men.  Solution works perfectly on Cygwin.  Thanks for making the effort!

Comment: Alternatively, you can get the pid of the process using this port: lsof -i :$port >/dev/null || echo "usused $port". However, you might need sudo to list processes of all users

Answer (score 4):

Same as above, but written as a function

```
function get_unused_port() {
  for port in $(seq 4444 65000);
  do
    echo -ne "\035" | telnet 127.0.0.1 $port > /dev/null 2>&1;
    [ $? -eq 1 ] && echo "$port" && break;
  done
}
FREE_PORT="$(get_unused_port)"
echo $FREE_PORT
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function doesn't depend on telnet/netcat as it generates a random port in the local port range and compares it with a list of ports currently used by running applications.

Should work on any *nix that supports proc filesystem. Generates a free ephemeral port to be used by your application.

```
function EPHEMERAL_PORT(){
    while true; do 
        LISTENING_PORTS=$(cat /proc/net/tcp | awk 'NR >1 {print $2}' | awk -F':' '{print $2}');
        LISTENING_PORTS=$(for PORT in ${LISTENING_PORTS}; do echo $((16#${PORT})); done|sort -g);
        # echo "32768 60999" | read LPORT UPORT
        read LPORT UPORT < /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_local_port_range
        MPORT=$[$LPORT + ($RANDOM % $UPORT)];
        if (echo "${LISTENING_PORTS[@]}" | grep -xqv $MPORT); then
            echo $MPORT;
            break;
        fi
    done
}
```

Apparently [TCP connections can be used as file descriptors](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/devref1.html) on linux. The following function uses that technique and should be faster than the previous one.

```
function EPHYMERAL_PORT(){
    LPORT=32768;
    UPORT=60999;
    while true; do
        MPORT=$[$LPORT + ($RANDOM % $UPORT)];
        (echo "" >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/${MPORT}) >/dev/null 2>&1
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo $MPORT;
            return 0;
        fi
    done
}
```

This is a cross platform function that uses [osquery](https://osquery.io/) to get a list of listening ports. Should also work on Windows.

```
function EPHYMERAL_PORT(){
    while true; do 
        echo "32768 60999" | read LPORT UPORT
        MPORT=$[$LPORT + ($RANDOM % $UPORT)];
        LISTENING_PORTS=$(osqueryi --header=false --list "select port from listening_ports order by port");
        if (echo "${LISTENING_PORTS[@]}" | grep -xqv $MPORT); then
            echo $MPORT;
            break;
        fi
    done
}
```

Usage instructions. Bind the output to a variable and use in scripts. Tested on Ubuntu 16.04

```
root@ubuntu:~> EPHYMERAL_PORT
59453
root@ubuntu:~> PORT=$(EPHYMERAL_PORT)
```

Comment: Aside: All-caps names are reserved for variables with meaning to the shell or operating system; the namespace of names with at least one lower-case character are reserved for applications. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph four, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable will overwrite any like-named environment variable.

Comment: Also, `$[ ... ]` is legacy syntax for compatibility with 1970s-era Bourne shell; the early-1990s POSIX sh standard (which ash, dash, and other shells implement) doesn't include it, but rather uses `$(( ))` for math.

Comment: You might also try to minimize your use of subshells: `if : >/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/$mport; then` doesn't have the performance impact of putting your open inside `( )`, and thus telling the shell to spawn a subprocess and perform the operation there.

Comment: To be clear, I really prefer this answer to the others available from a big-picture perspective; the tactical problems, however, prevent me from being able to showcase it as a best-practice example.

Comment: (Oh, another point -- the `function` keyword has no benefit whatsoever over the POSIX-defined function definition syntax of just `funcname() { body; }`, unlike other bashisms which provide improved semantics over the POSIX spec; thus, using it is paying a penalty in portability for no gain in return).

Comment: ...oh, another point: The ABS is really not a good reference -- it's *full* of bad-practice examples, and only very occasionally maintained; that it has the search ranking it does is a travesty on the same level as W3Schools. Consider replacing the link with one to [the bash-hackers wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#valid_redirection_targets_and_sources) or [the official manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). (The [Wooledge wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) is another reputable source, but doesn't have on-point content here).

Comment: Superb comments Charles. This showcases the depth of your knowledge on Linux/Shell/POSIX topics. Kudos Professor !!!