# Jupyterhub multiple web applications port problem

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub

at my firm we have a jupyterhub/lab installed and is used by roughly 70-100 people in a secure network that can only be accessed to from work. Recently the idea of hosting web-applications for short time use came up, but we are having port problems. User A is running a web application on port 5000, and User B can’t use the port because it is already in use. Port 5000 is default, it can be changed but this is not the behavior we want. Does anyone know of a way for web-applications to run on the same port in the same environment? Have looked into server-proxy but i do not really understand it. Is the way to achieve this really to be running a vm for each user securing that the port is not in use?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you trying to allow users to share access with each other? or just host for their own viewing? for the latter - jupyter-server-proxy is really the way to go. how are you setting up your jupyterhub cluster? this should just be a matter of enabling this extension module and installing the package in the user environments.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado it is a single server running all the notebooks on same server. /proxy/port works fine, but if another user uses same port then that is a problem. The host is ment for own viewing

Comment: if your question is "how can I configure jupyter-server-proxy to serve user-specific ports?" then I'd ask that as a different, well defined question in order to attract answers from experts in jupyter-server-proxy. If it's "can I open the same port with two different applications" the answer is no. if it's "how can I find an open port?" this seems like a pretty standard problem that doesn't have anything to do with jupyterlab. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6942097/finding-next-open-port/37752767. good luck! :)